# Auto Increment in sql with specific name

Tags: mysql, sql

i need autoincrement. for start like abc_1,abc_2. like this format? below shown code is for auto increment. but i need format like abc_ is constatanct then auto increment, format like abc_1,abc_2..

### **CODE**

```
sql = "CREATE TABLE MY_TABLE
(
  table_id int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, 
  PRIMARY KEY(table_id),
  table_1 varchar(45),
  table_2 varchar(45),
  table_3 varchar(999),
  table_4 varchar(45)
 )"
```

Comment: Is there a really need of this ? you can also show this type of result in your select statement by using your auto_increment number

Comment: Big question - Why?  When you ask a question, sometimes the "why you want to this" is more important than the "what you want to do".  My guess is that you don't need to do what you are asking and that the ABC_nnn can be achieved another way.

Comment: yes, i really need of this.

Comment: yes mr.simo. i need it in generate insurance id's with ins_1,ins_2 to give some value to assign values to the customers.

Comment: @saikrishna then generate this type of number in your application level code i.e(php/asp etc)

Comment: ok. is it difficult in Sql..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have 2 options - both include keeping the autoincrement field exactly as it is.

1st Option is to add a short char type field, which simply stores your Alpha part.  When you want to retrieve the whole key, then you can `SELECT (alpha_part + table_id) as ID`. As you can see this generates smaller storage, but requires more work for each select statement.

2nd option is to add a longer column that gets populated by an insert trigger normally.  It is simply storing the concatenation on creation and then you don't have to concatenate it when you want to select it.  This option also allows you to create an index or clustered index easier.

```
CREATE TABLE MY_TABLE ( 
table_id int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, PRIMARY KEY(table_id), 
alpha_part varchar(10) NOT NULL,   -- This 
display_id varchar(40) NOT NULL,   -- OR This (not both)
table_1 varchar(45), 
table_2 varchar(45), 
table_3 varchar(999), 
table_4 varchar(45) )
```

"Database Id" and "Insurance Policy Id" are two separate entities - they may contain the "same" number, but don't mix up what the database needs to perform effectively, with what your business application needs to generate IDs for customers.  Business rules and database Id are separate entities.  You can "seed" a policy Id from a database generated one, but if something changes the policy id (yes this happens) your database suddenly needs to be refactored and you don't want that to happen.

Comment: i am basic level in SQL. can u help me out.

Answer (score 0):

You could add another column to derive this value, then have a trigger that automatically updates this column to add the derived value whenever a row is inserted.

However, it is not clear why this would be needed.  It is likely better to just store the number and derive the form `abc_123` where that value needs to be used.

Answer (score 0):

It was an interesting thing. so I googled custom auto increment structure and found some links. Most of the people are saying that its better to use trigger before insertion and I think it can be on possible solution for your problem. Look at the following link.

http://www.experts-exchange.com/Database/MySQL/Q_27602627.html

Comment: it is asking Premium Membership Mr.vaguness

Comment: use this link:http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CCAQFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.experts-exchange.com%2FDatabase%2FMySQL%2FQ_27602627.html&ei=a3saVJW3DoegyATy34LICA&usg=AFQjCNH3KVRE__wVCdatqav-soHnQxKbJw&sig2=gt8trbhlMOVQcB8amW75uA&bvm=bv.75097201,d.aWw&cad=rja